# RedirectLimitExceeded while running chef client

Tags: chef, vagrant

I'm using for the first time *chef solo* for provisioning a Windows box created with Vagrant.

While trying to apply the [sql_server](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/sql_server) cookbook I get the following error:

```
[2013-11-14T09:41:24+01:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2013-11-14T09:41:24+01:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2013-11-14T09:41:24+01:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2013-11-14T09:41:24+01:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::RedirectLimitExceeded:
windows_package[Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (32-bit)] (sql_server::server line 39)
had an error: Chef::Exceptions::RedirectLimitExceeded:
remote_file[/var/chef/cache/SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe] (dynamically defined)
had an error: Chef::Exceptions::RedirectLimitExceeded:
Chef::Exceptions::RedirectLimitExceeded
```

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The RedirectLimitExceeded Exception is a result of there being too many DNS redirects between the original URL that remote_file is trying to retrieve and the final URL. I had the same issue and resolved it by changing the origional URL to the URL that it was redirecting to thus eliminating a redirect which got me under the redirect count.

You can see the change that was made here in to resolve the same issue:

```
-default['openresty']['pcre']['url']      = "http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcre/files/pcre/#{node['openresty']['pcre']['version']}/pcre-#{node['openresty']['pcre']['version']}.tar.bz2/download"
+default['openresty']['pcre']['url']      = "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pcre/pcre/#{node['openresty']['pcre']['version']}/pcre-#{node['openresty']['pcre']['version']}.tar.bz2/download"
```

You can set it somehow with the redirect_limit var but I've not attempted to do that yet.

Hope this helps...

Edit:
Also, you can find out the URL further down the redirection line by doing something like this...

```
$ wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/adium/files/Adium_1.5.7.dmg/download
    --2014-02-25 19:09:04--  http://sourceforge.net/projects/adium/files/Adium_1.5.7.dmg/download
    Resolving sourceforge.net... 216.34.181.60
    Connecting to sourceforge.net|216.34.181.60|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
    Location: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/adium/Adium_1.5.7.dmg?r=&ts=1393373344&use_mirror=hivelocity [following]
    --2014-02-25 19:09:04--  http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/adium/Adium_1.5.7.dmg?r=&ts=1393373344&use_mirror=hivelocity
    Resolving downloads.sourceforge.net... 216.34.181.59
    Connecting to downloads.sourceforge.net|216.34.181.59|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
    Location: http://hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net/project/adium/Adium_1.5.7.dmg [following]
    --2014-02-25 19:09:04--  http://hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net/project/adium/Adium_1.5.7.dmg
    Resolving hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net... 74.50.101.106
    Connecting to hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net|74.50.101.106|:80... connected.
    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
    Length: 23999416 (23M) [application/x-apple-diskimage]
    Saving to: ‘download’

    100%[===================================================================================================================================>] 23,999,416  1014KB/s   in 25s

    2014-02-25 19:09:29 (941 KB/s) - ‘download’ saved [23999416/23999416]
```

This led me to find that I could use this URL instead: http://hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net/project/adium/Adium_1.5.7.dmg

Comment: FYI I changed http to htte because I could not post more than two linmks...